# phpMyAdmin shows PHP code instead of executing it

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, homebrew, httpd.conf

I just have installed via homebrow apache, php, and Mysql on my mac, everything works fine.

But i tried to install phpMyAdmin, still from homebrew, i have edited my httpd.conf as mentionned.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
 <Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
     </IfModule>
     <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </IfModule>
 </Directory>
```

but when i reach http://localhost/phpmyadmin it shows the code of index.php, which tells me that the alias is OK.

http://localhost/ with a phpinfo works fine. But the folder is in /Users/my-username/Sites/
I tried to put phpmyadmin in this folder but it launch a 404.

How to force a folder to process php with apache ?

Comment: there is possibility that any PHP code will not work try it out with minimal `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` PHP file to see if apache is configured properly. If not, try restarting Apache

Comment: did you done chmod?

Comment: @PavelJanicek this code works great like the phpinfo(), but the phpmyadmin folder is not in the same place, it's where hombrew installed it on my mac. The phpmyadmin page is treated like html, but the path is OK. i have restarted apach already.

Comment: @TechSpot thess files are on my mac, i changed the permissions to read and write, but it did nothing to my problem

Comment: Homebrew installs to /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin and asks you to configure the statements to httpd.conf rather than putting the folder in your Sites directory. To start with, you should move it back to /usr/local/share and run `brew doctor` to make sure the installation is in good condition. Then, you should restart your Apache, try again, and report back to us any errors in the Apache error log.

Comment: go to the phpmyadmin folder


`cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin`
and run 
`php -S 127.0.0.1:8910`